# Есть ли слово "нижеперечисленные"?

Tags: орфография

Ворд мне его подчеркивает (но и слово "голубой" подчеркивает). Но вообще, есть такое слово? Например, во фразе: "...нужно предъявить нижеперечисленные документы".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вполне нормальное слово для официально-делового стиля. Ворд подчёркивает все слова, незафиксированные в словарях. Однако составные слова, вроде "нижеперечисленный", могут в словарях и не оказаться, что не мешает их свободному употреблению в речи. Особенности написания данного слова можно просмотреть по ссылке на справочную службу [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramma.ru/ARR/?fnd=2&fl=1&num=1152)